# Operator Function Called Infinite

Tags: c++

I am getting runtime error, Could anyone figure out why there is an infinite call in this programme and which line is doing it

http://ideone.com/0CWZTD

Here goes my Code

```
class opOverload{
public:
    bool operator==(opOverload temp){
        if(*this == temp){
            cout << "both same";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            cout <<"both different";
            return false;
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    opOverload a1,a2;
    a1==a2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `*this == temp` is going to call?

Comment: Installing a debugger would have solved that issue

Comment: Ya right deW1  actually my brain got tired as  continuosly studying for past 15 hours so unable to figured out

Comment: How did you prove it's an infinite call?

Comment: got runtime error in ideone which mostly happen on infinte call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `*this == temp` is equivalent to `(*this).operator==(temp)`, which obviously calls the same `operator==` you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
*this == temp
```

will again invoke your operator overload, so you are basically doing:

```
A(){
   A();
}
```

This is a self recursive function call, and you are obviously not making progress (towards the base case, even worse...there is no base case)